# Прошу объяснить возможность использования глагола "приведите" в моем примере. Возможна ли такая формулировка?

Tags: глаголы

*1. Приведите правила эксплуатации и условия безопасной работы на взбивальных машинах типа МВ-35 М.*

Comment: Спасибо, но мне необходимо объяснение

Comment: Объяснения обычно пишут в ответах, а это редактирование вашего  вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Такая формулировка вполне возможна.
Восьмое значение слова *привести* по Большому толковому словарю:

> Сообщить что-л. в подкрепление своего мнения, сослаться на что-л.,
> процитировать что-л. *П. пример. П. цитату. П. данные об успеваемости.
> В доказательство п. слова классика. П. в пример кого-, что-л. Встреча
> привела на память, на ум давние события* (заставила вспомнить,
> напомнила).

Answer (score 0):

У меня замечание **по стилю** (а не по грамматике), я бы **лучше** написала так:

*1. **Назовите  правила** эксплуатации и условия безопасной работы на взбивальных машинах типа МВ-35 М.*

Здесь меня смущает прямое значение глагола "приводить"— *приведите сюда кого-то.*

В то же время вполне корректно сочетание "приведите примеры" (на какую-то тему).

Почему? Ну, примеры надо искать, чтобы их "привести", а правила находятся известно где: в данном случае в технической документации, а правила письма — в справочнике Розенталя или в ПАС

Comment: "Назовите" мне кажется не слишком удачным вариантом. "Назовите правила" = перечислите заголовки правил (к примеру, правило 7 пункт 4.6). А "приведите правила" = процитируйте текст соответствующих правил. Мне так слышится, не уверен в объективной точности коннотаций.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что эти правила не длиннее заголовков, поэтому их надо именно перечислить. Вероятно, это экзамен  на подтверждение квалификации, там длинных речей не надо.  А так кто его знает... Мне любопытно, почему автор вопроса сомневается в  правильности формулировки.